# How to specify different formatting for different files in VS code/Prettier

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, prettier

Does anyone know if it's possible to have VS Code auto format different file extensions differently?

For example I want:

JS - 4 spaces, CSS - 2 spaces and HTML - 2 spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Language Specific Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings). In your `settings.json` do like so:

```
{
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 4
  },
  "[css]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 2
  },
  "[html]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 2
  }
}
```